# javascript pass arguments into sibling object

Tags: javascript, arguments

I have something like this:

```
function showFunction () {
  // need position and place
}

var obj = {
  position: 1,
  place: 2,
  onShow: showFunction
}
```

How do I access position and place from showFunction?

Comment: Pass `obj` in as a parm: `showFunction(obj);`

Comment: @JonathanM: That, or prototype the function and use `this.position`.

Comment: @Truth no need to, the way this is constructed `this` inside `showFunction` will point to `obj`

Comment: Does "sibling object" mean they're in the same variable scope? If so, then just go ahead and use `obj` in the function. You can pass the function elsewhere, and it'll still work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) should work:

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its *this* is set to
>   the object the method is called on.

```
function showFunction() {
    console.log(this.position, this.place);
}
var obj = {
    position: 1,
    place: 2,
    onShow: showFunction
}
obj.onShow()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since functions are hoisted in JavaScript, you simply refer to `.position` and `.place` inside the function as you would outside the function:

```
function showFunction() {
  return obj.position;
}
```

But if for some reason you can't access `obj`, you can, as Jonathan said, pass `obj` as an argument to `showFunction()`.

```
function showFunction(obj) {
    return obj.position;
}

var obj = {
  position: 1,
  place: 2,
  onShow: function() {
      return showFunction(obj);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're making `showFunction` a member of `obj`, you can access the object via `this`.

```
function showFunction () {
    var a, b;
    a = this.position;
    b = this.place;
}

var obj = {
  position: 1,
  place: 2,
  onShow: showFunction
}
```

Alternatively, you could access `obj` just like you would outside of the function:

```
function showFunction () {
    var a, b;
    a = obj.position;
    b = obj.place;
}
```